# Combining FEs in feols.fit

Tags: r, fixest

When using fixest's feols it is simple to add combinations of fixed-effects with `^` as in `z ~ x1 + x2 | fe_1^fe_2`.

However, how could I implement this type of interaction in feols.fit, which requires matrices/vectors instead of a formula?

Assuming that `z`, `fe_1` and `fe_2` are now vectors and that a matrix `X0` contains the variables `x1` and `x2`, I tried

```
feols.fit(y = z,
          X = X0,
          fixef_df = fe_1^fe_2)
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: `fixef_df = paste(fe_1,fe_2)` works.